# How to find the distance between words in a sentence in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, for-loop

I am trying to write a function that finds the distance between words in a sentence given the choice of words in sentence. For example

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
 quick
 lazy
 The output would be: 6
```

The only example I have been able to find this example but it does not work:

```js
/**
 * @function findMimimumWordDistance
 * @param words
 * @param wordA
 * @param WordB
 * @return {number} minDistance
 */
function findMimimumWordDistance(words, wordA, wordB) {
  let wordAIndex = null;
  let wordBIndex = null;
  let minDistance = null;
  let length = words.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    /**
     * In the first 2 conditional statuments
     * check to see if the word is found in the collection
     * Assign that word to the value of i which is a number
     */
    if (words[i] === wordA) {
      wordAIndex === i;
    }

    if (words[i] === wordB) {
      wordBIndex === i;
    }

    /**
     * In the following conditional statement
     */
    if (wordAIndex !== null && wordBIndex !== null) {
      let distance = Math.abs(wordAIndex - wordBIndex);

      if (minDistance === null || minDistance > distance) {
        minDistance = distance;
      }
    }

  }


  return minDistance
}
```

What can I do to get the desired output?

Comment: You have a typo where you are matching wordB, you are updating wordAIndex where you should be updating wordBIndex.

Comment: @HamzaArshad Thank you just corrected that

Comment: Maybe you pass as the first argument the complete string? This needs to hold an array of the words not the string. So first you have to do str.split(" ");

Comment: I have added the answer, you also must be assigning 'i' to variables using = not ===.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code should work as expected:

```js
/**
 * @function findMimimumWordDistance
 * @param words
 * @param wordA
 * @param WordB
 * @return {number} minDistance
 */
function findMimimumWordDistance(wordsStr, wordA, wordB) {
  let wordAIndex = null;
  let wordBIndex = null;
  let minDistance = null;
  let words = wordsStr.split(" ");
  let length = words.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    /**
     * In the first 2 conditional statuments
     * check to see if the word is found in the collection
     * Assign that word to the value of i which is a number
     */
    if (words[i] === wordA) {
      wordAIndex = i;
    }

    if (words[i] === wordB) {
      wordBIndex = i;
    }

    /**
     * In the following conditional statement
     */
    if (wordAIndex !== null && wordBIndex !== null) {
      let distance = Math.abs(wordAIndex - wordBIndex);

      if (minDistance === null || minDistance > distance) {
        minDistance = distance;
      }
    }

  }


  return minDistance
}
```

Comment: When I run it I get null. This is what I ran
`findMimimumWordDistance("The quick brown fox jumped", "quick", "jumped");`

Comment: @AmenRa please check updated answer, it will work now as per your parameters.

Answer (score 1):

A more compact function that uses the JavaScript built-in methods:

```js
function findDist(string, word1, word2) {
  // copy string and remove punctuation
  let str = string.replace(/\./gi, '');
  // split str into array of words
  const words = str.split(' ');
  // get first location of word1, word2
  const iWord1 = words.findIndex(word => word === word1);
  const iWord2 = words.findIndex(word => word === word2);
  if (iWord1 === -1 || iWord2 === -1) { return null; }
  
  return Math.abs(iWord2 - iWord1);
}

const sentence = "A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";
const w1 = 'quick', w2 = 'lazy';
const distance = findDist(sentence, w1, w2);

document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML =
  `The distance between "${w1}" and "${w2}" is ${distance}.`;
```

```html
<div id="answer"></div>
```

Comment: If I am right, it will not find the minimum distance.

Comment: Right, not minimum distance. Was that requested? From the question: "a function that finds the distance between words in a sentence"

Answer (score 1):

My take on this one

- Remove all the words before wordA from the sentence.
- Count the words in the resulting sentence.
- Subtract the words from wordB to end.

it's quite weak in this form, the sentence should probably be stripped from punctuation and all the strings maybe transformed to lowercase ...

```js
function findMinimumWordDistance(sentence, wordA, wordB) {

  if(! sentence.includes(wordA) || ! sentence.includes(wordB)) {
    return; // undefined
  }

  let wordAToEnd = sentence.substring(sentence.indexOf(wordA));
  let wordBToEnd = sentence.substring(sentence.indexOf(wordB));

  return wordAToEnd.split(" ").length - wordBToEnd.split(" ").length;
}
```

... or you could count the spaces in the string `s.substring(s.indexOf(wordA), s.indexOf(wordB))`

```js
const ALL_BUT_LETTER_AND_SPACE = '/[^a-z|^\s/g';
const ALL_BUT_SPACE = '/[^\s]/g';
const SPACES = '/[\s]*/g';

function findMinimumWordDistance(sentence, wordA, wordB) {
  sentence = sentence
  .toLowerCase()
  .replace(ALL_BUT_LETTER_AND_SPACE, ' ')
  .replace(SPACES, ' ');

  wordA = wordA.toLowerCase();
  wordB = wordB.toLowerCase();

  return sentence
  .substring(sentence.indexOf(wordA), sentence.indexOf(wordB))
  .replace(ALL_BUT_SPACE, '')
  .length;
}
```